# Does SqlConnectionStringBuilder requires an escape char if server name contains a backslash

Tags: .net, database-connection

Given a SQL Server name of SQLSERVER\SQLSERVER does SqlConnectionStringBuilder requires an escape char in front of the backslash in the server name.

```
var sqlConnStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "SQLSERVER\\SQLSERVER"
};
```

Comment: The second one, but not because SqlConnectionStringBuilder  requires it. It is needed because in C# a single backslash escapes the next char. So your first example will become "SQLSERVER<escapedS>QLSERVER". Not going to work (as <escapedS> is an unrecognized escape sequence)

Comment: They could have baked something into SqlConnectionStringBuilder class to handle single escape characters in strings... that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I see you point but that string (the first example) is a syntax error for the C# compiler, no way to reach the class constructor

Comment: Yes, looks like a brain freeze on my part but there is actually a textbox in the UI bound to a property so my confusion was more about whether the server name typed in by the user was already 'literalized' or they needed type in the escape char...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the first example because that code results in a syntax error to the C# compiler. It is the C# language that requires you  to have two backslashes to represent a single one. If you don't use two backslashes the C# parser tries to 'escape' the following character (the S) but there is no escape sequence for \S and thus you get the error.

```
CS1009 Unrecognized escape sequence
```

If, just as an example, your server is called "testdb" (lowercase) then writing

```
var sqlConnStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "SQLSERVER\testdb"
};
```

will pass the compilation but fails the opening of the connection because \t is a recognized escape sequence and will be treated as a TAB character (09).

You could see this in action with a simple code like this

```
void Main()
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"d:\temp\testescapechar.txt", "SQLSERVER\testdb");
}
```

and then looking at the hexdecimal content of the file you will find:

```
0:  53 51 4C 53 45 52 56 45 52 09 65 73 74 64 62
     S  Q  L  S  E  R  V  E  R ^^  e  s  t  d  b
```

I forgot to mention that you could use the verbatim string syntax that allows you to write

```
var sqlConnStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = @"SQLSERVER\SQLSERVER"
};
```

Here the @ character nullifies the escape sequence pattern and treats the characters at their literal value thus allowing the single backslash to represent itself